# SQL is not showing up when trying to connect to it via odbc from a client computer after migrating database to a new server

Tags: sql-server, sql, sql-server-2012

I installed SQL 2012 on a new Server 2022 vm and restored a database on the new server from a SQL generated backup. The new SQLserver/instance is not showing up in the Odbc client on a windows client.
I have verified that the port 1433 is outbound and inbound rules are set to allow.
I have also tried disabling the firewall although disabling for "Domains" is not allowed as it for some reason is an administrator setting.
I have tried SQL Server client and SQl Native Client Server 11.00.
When I did the initial SQL server install there was a warning that there may be a port issue but did not elaborate.

Do I need to allow other port besides 1433?
What steps do I need to do trouble shoot this?

[image: Odbc configuration connector]

Comment: **The new SQL Server/instance is not showing up in the ODBC client on a windows client.** - What do you mean, exactly? It doesn't just show up in the client. How are you trying to connect? By ip address? Name? Can you post an image? Is the SQL Browser service running?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/announcements/sql-server-2012-windows-server-2012-2012-r2-end-of-support

Comment: `What steps do I need to do` check the port that your SQL Server service is listening on. You can use SQL Config manager and `netstat -ano`

Comment: When I use the odbc connector on the Windows 11 pc to add a connector with SqlServer Client or Native client 11 the drop down field combo box does not show the new server nor does typing in the servername\databasename produce a connection to the server. Instead it times out with error 17 and error 52.  The SQL Browser is running on the new Server.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to connect via Named Pipes. Is that protocol enabled on the SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, named pipes.  In the SQL Configuration manager all of the protocols are enabled including named pipes and TCp with port 1433

Comment: Are you connecting to the server by name or by ip address in the ODBC wizard? If by IP address, is the ip address correct and is it in the same network as the client? If by name, does the name resolve to the correct ip address?

Comment: Netstat -ano shows no listening on port 1433

Comment: Clue: Something new that I found is that when I use the SQL Server Client in ODBC 64 bit it connects to the database and tests successfuly. But, when I use ODBC 32 with the same SQL Server client the test fails.  Unfortuantley, the Access interface being used is 32-Bit.

Answer (score 0):

It is TCP Port issue, I think.
You need to try changing TCP Port from 1433.
Steps for this.
-Under the `IPAll` section, look for the `TCP Port` value.
Default is `1433`.
If this port is already in use by another application or service, you need to change it to a different available port.
Restart SQL Server.

Comment: I don't think this should be the case.  This is a brand new Windows 2022 server install.  Nothing else is running on the server.  If I did do this what port would I use?  Would the client odbc see the other non 1433 port listening automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Let's test possible things step by step:

1. If your client is a machine different from your server, can you access it using `telnet [Server name/ip] 1433`?
   -- if [1] passed, then:
2. In some cases, you need to enable Named Pipes on your server (needs to restart SQL Server service)
3. Check you installed the latest SQL Server 2012 Native Client (by now 11.0.7001.0) and the proper edition (x86, x64)

Comment: When I execute oicl-sql 1433 or by ip address 1433 it says it connect failed.  Named Pipes are enabled on the SQL server.  The odd thing is that the ODBC test completes sucessfully for 64 Bit Odbc using the SQL Server Client only.  All other cleints will not work nor will SQL Server Client work on 32 bit ODBC.